# Could you please tell me which of the following two sentences is correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Having had the same best friend for more than 10 years who I'm so mentally connected to is very precious.

or

> Having the same best friend for more than 10 years who I'm so mentally connected to is very precious.

Comment: *Having a loving spouse is important* seems like a natural thing to say. I can't say *Having **had** a loving spouse is important* is "ungrammatical" (it's syntactically fine), but I can't easily imagine a context where someone might say that.

Comment: Here in my context  i mentioned time period so was a bit confused . So using having here is correct  i suppose?

Comment: If you *still* have that same best friend, and ***having*** him as a friend is still precious to you, use the Present Continuous. If you ***no longer*** have him as a best friend, but it's still important to you ***now*** that you ***once did have such a friend***, use the Present Perfect *(**having had**)*.

Comment: Both are very poorly written.

Comment: How can i improve these two lines? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and have different meaning, so you need to explain which context you are referring in each of them.

Comment: Doesn't having had here refer that the best friend i still have was the same in past too?  Another question is it a bad way/ grammatically poor to start a sentence with 'having had'?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the different tenses you have used we can't be quite sure whether he/she is *still* your best friend. *This answer assumes he/she **is***.

FumbleFingers is right. "Having" feels more natural than "having had".

This is one way to say it:

> Having the same best friend for more than 10 years - someone to whom
>   I'm so mentally connected - is very precious to me.

Some people think *whom* is old fashioned, so you could say,

> Having the same best friend for more than 10 years - someone I'm so
>   mentally connected to - is very precious to me.

Or for old-fashioned, perfect English with extra emphasis:

> Having the same best friend for more than 10 years - someone to whom
>   I'm so mentally connected - is, and always has been, very precious to
>   me.

If that person is no longer your best friend, tell us and we will try again.

And it *is* perfectly OK to start a sentence with *Having had*. And you are clearly talking about only one person.